# jsonSchema attribute conditionally required based on uri parameter

Tags: jsonschema

Consider an API with an endpoint in which you pass a parameter `foo` as part of the URL-path, and pass some parameters as json in the body of a POST request.

- This uri parameter `foo` must have one of the values `fooBar` and `fooBaz`. Otherwise the request gest a 404.
- If the value of `foo` is `fooBar` then the body attribute `bar` is required.
- If the value of `foo` is `fooBaz` then the body attribute `baz` is required.

How do I specify a jsonSchema for such an endpoint?

---

An example for such a request would be:

```
POST /path/to/endpoint/fooBar HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 20
{"bar":"something"}
```

---

So far I came up with the following based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required) and [that](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html#rfc.section.6.2) but I have no idea if this is correct.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "foo": { "enum": ["fooBar", "fooBaz"] }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": { "$ref": "#/definitions/foo" },
        "bar": { "type": "string" },
        "baz": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "links": [{
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "/path/to/endpoint/{foo}",
        "hrefSchema": {
            "properties": {
                "foo": {"$ref": "#/definitions/foo"}
            }
        }
    }],
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "foo": { "enum": ["fooBar"] }
            },
            "required": ["bar"]
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "foo": { "enum": ["fooBaz"] }
            },
            "required": ["baz"]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON Schema validation is not aware of the URI that the data being validated came from (if any).  You can use JSON Hyper-Schema to tell your users how to send that data in the way you expect, but you will still need to do an additional check on the server-side to validate that the request was sent properly.

Before I get into the solution, I want to point out a couple things.  Your `$schema` is set to "draft-03".  If you really need "draft-03", this solution won't work.  `anyOf`, `allOf` and the array form of `required` were added in "draft-04".  `hrefSchema` was added in "draft-06".  Since "draft-06" is brand new and is not well supported yet and you don't need `hrefSchema` anyway, I'm going to assume "draft-04" ("draft-05" was effectively skipped).

The next thing to mention is that you are using `id` wrong.  It should be the identifier for *your* schema.  You usually don't need this, but if you do, it should be the full URI identifying your schema.  That is how my solution uses it.

Last thing before I get into the solution.  If you are using the `link` keyword, you are using JSON Hyper-Schema and your `$schema` should reflect that.  It should have "hyper-schema" instead of "schema" at the end of the URI.

Now the solution.  I broke it into two parts, the schema that you put through the validator and the hyper-schema that tells users how to make the request.  You've got the first one right.  I only fixed the `$schema` and `id`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com/schema/my-foo-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "enum": ["fooBar", "fooBaz"] },
    "bar": { "type": "string" },
    "baz": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "enum": ["fooBar"] }
      },
      "required": ["bar"]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "enum": ["fooBaz"] }
      },
      "required": ["baz"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Next is the hyper-schema.  You can't reference anything external (href, instance data) in a request schema, but you can write your schema so that it matches your `href`.  The duplication is unfortunate, but that's the way you have to do it.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema#",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "http://example.com/rel/my-foo-relation",
      "href": "/path/to/endpoint/fooBar",
      "method": "POST",
      "schema": {
        "allOf": [{ "$ref": "http://example.com/schema/my-foo-schema" }],
        "properties": {
          "foo": { "enum": ["fooBar"] }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "rel": "http://example.com/rel/my-foo-relation",
      "href": "/path/to/endpoint/fooBaz",
      "method": "POST",
      "schema": {
        "allOf": [{ "$ref": "http://example.com/schema/my-foo-schema" }],
        "properties": {
          "foo": { "enum": ["fooBaz"] }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "/path/to/endpoint"
    }
  ]
}
```

Usually when I come across something that is difficult to model with hyper-schema, it means that I am doing something overly complicated with my API and I need to refactor.  I suggest taking a few minutes to think about alternative designs where this switching on an enum isn't necessary.