# jsonschema validation of properties required and/or conditionally required

Tags: properties, conditional-statements, option-type, jsonschema, required

I need to validate a json object that always have 2 properties:

- type
- name

type can be "A", "B" or "C",

when type is "A", also the property "foo" is required and no additional properties are allowed.

OK:

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "name": "a",
    "foo": "a",
}
```

Not OK:

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "name": "a",
    "foo": "a",
    "lol": "a"
}
```

when type is "B", the property "bar" is required and no additional properties are allowed.

when type is "C", the property "bar" is required and optionally also "zen" property can be present.

OK:

```
{
    "type": "C",
    "name": "a",
    "bar": "a",
    "zen": "a"
}

{
    "type": "C",
    "name": "a",
    "bar": "a",
}
```

Not OK:

```
{
    "type": "C",
    "name": "a",
    "bar": "a",
    "lol": "a" 
}
```

Unfortunately the outstanding answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required) partially cover my case, however I did not managed to build a jsonschema that works for me.

edit:

Here is what I tried.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["A", "B", "C"]
        },
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "foo": {"type": "string"},
        "bar": {"type": "string"},
        "zen": {"type": "string"},
    },
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {"type": {"enum": ["A"]}},
            "required": ["foo"],
        },
        {
            "properties": {"type": {"enum": ["B"]}},
            "required": ["bar"],
        },
        {
            "properties": {"type": {"enum": ["C"]}},
            "required": ["bar"],
        },
    ]
}
```

My problem is that setting the field "additionalProperties" to false inside the  objects in "anyOf" does not give me the expected result.

for instance the following json pass the validation despite it has the additional property "lol"

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "name": "a",
    "foo": "a",
    "lol": "a"
}
```

Comment: I updated my post to include the example I tried and the reason why this solution does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema is a constraint system where the constraints of each subschema are evaluated separately.  That means that "additionalProperties" can only "see" the "properties" or "patternProperties" within the same immediate schema object.

Additionally, it cannot "see" properties based on "required", only on "properties" and "patternProperties".

As far as I can tell, if you were setting "additionalProperties": false inside *each* branch of the anyOf, none of this should work as the only allowed property would be "type".  If you did that and it is allowing properties other than "type", then I would want to know what implementation you are using.

Comment: so basically the only way to implement the rigid  schema I need is to use anyOf with the list of schema that validate exactly what i need, I wanted to reuse some properties but seems that this is not possible.

Comment: In draft-06, you can do some re-use with `propertyNames`, although it's not incredibly concise.

Answer (score 1):

The following schema worked for me on your example.  Hopefully this helps others.  Trick was to use a combination of `additionalProperties` and `maxProperties`, with `required` in the right places:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "zen": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "type"
  ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "A"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "maxProperties": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "B"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "bar"
        ],
        "maxProperties": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "C"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "bar"
        ],
        "maxProperties": 4
      }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While working on my game, Bolero: The Lost Isle, I wanted a good way to validate all the data I needed to make, but many of the objects in my game had inheritance structures. I then started learning JSON Schema as a potential solution. I've been editing my schema in Hackolade, but you can get the gist by seeing one of the model diagrams I've made (btw, the hard vs. dashed outlines convey required-true vs. required false, excluding the subschema). [image]

The only object here that has 'additionalProperties' set to 'true' are the 'Data' on the same layers as the oneOf splits. The 'Data' within the subschemas (as well as the subschema) have 'additionalProperties' set to 'false' which overwrites the 'true'. The 'Type' strings work similar to your solution, they each have const values set to the same thing as the titles of the subschema.

I've implemented this schema in Visual Studio Code and the validation and autocompletion have been great!