# Properties based on enum value in JSON Schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I'm building a json schema definition which has a fixed set of controls that I've currently limited with an `enum`. However, not all properties are relevant for all controls.

I only want to require an `options` property if the `controlType` = `dropdown`

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "controlType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["title", "dropdown", "button"]
      },
      "options:": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {"type": "string"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I conditionally include / require a field in a json schema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use `IF..Then..Else`  <sup>[new in Draft-07](http://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html)</sup>

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "controlType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["title", "dropdown", "button"]
      },
      "options:": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {"type": "string"}
      }
    },
      
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "controlType": {"const": "dropdown"}
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": ["options"]
    }
  }
}
```

### Use [`oneOf`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof) or [`anyOf`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#anyof)

This can be useful if you have a property that has a limited number of acceptable values (such as an enum), but each possible value needs to be individually mapped.

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "controlType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["title", "dropdown", "button"]
      },
      "options:": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {"type": "string"}
      }
    },  
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "controlType": {"const": "dropdown"}
        },
        "required": ["controlType", "options"]
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "controlType": {"const": "title"}
        },
        "required": ["controlType"]
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "controlType": {"const": "button"}
        },
        "required": ["controlType"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Further Reading

- [Conditionally require attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/1366033)
- [Applying subschemas conditionally](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html)
- [Combining schemas](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html)

Comment: But how do you do this when using `$ref`?? I have an enum defined in a different file, how do I forge an object to have a property for each enum value in that instance?