# Object properties based on $ref enum in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have already looked at:

- [Properties based on enum value in JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139516/properties-based-on-enum-value-in-json-schema)
- [JSON schema for dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697209/json-schema-for-dynamic-properties)
- [JSON Schema $ref for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583994/json-schema-ref-for-properties)

---

I need my JSON schema to enforce that an object has all properties from an enum and I cannot puzzle out how.

**stuff.list.json**

Note: Imagine this, but much longer.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "ListOfStuff",
    "description": "List of stuff",
    "enum": [
        "Thing1",
        "Thing2",
        "Thing3"
    ],
    "uniqueItems": true
}
```

**stuff.schema.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "Stuff Defined",
    "description": "Stuff in detail",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        /* a property for each enum value of stuff.list.json  */: { <----- ???
            "type": "array",
            "items": { /* Schema for each item */ }
        }
    },
    "required": [ /* $ref: ./stuff.list.json ?? */ ]
 }
```

The output I'm aiming for it to enforce is:

```json
 {
     "Thing1": [],
     "Thing2": [],
     "Thing3": []
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [`required` keyword](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties)?   You can put it in a definition and reference it later:

```
"$defs": {
  "required_properties": {
    "required": [
      "Thing1",
      "Thing2",
      "Thing3"
    ]
  }
},
...
```

and then in your main schema:

```
{
  ...,
  "type": "object",
  "$ref": "stuff.list.json#/$defs/required_properties",
  ...,
}
```