# JsonSchema: Validate type based on value of another property

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am using the following schema to validate my json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "title": " Rules",
    "description": "Describes a set of rules",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "rules": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "precedence": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "minimum": 0
                    },
                    "conditions": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "field": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "enum": [ "Name", "Size" ]
                                },
                                "relation": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "enum": [ "is", "is not", "is not one of", "is one of" ]
                                },
                                "value": {
                                    "type": ["array", "string", "number"]
                                }
                            },
                            "required": ["field", "relation", "value"],
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        }
                    }                       
                },
                "required": ["precedence", "conditions"],
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["rules"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I want to set up a dependency to validate that when the value of the `relation` property has the value `is one of` or the value `is not one of`, then the type of the `value` property can only be `array`

For example, the following json should not validate because it uses the relation value `is not one of` and the `value` property is not an array:

```
{
    "rules": [{
            "precedence": 0,
            "conditions": [{
                    "field": "Name",
                    "relation": "is not one of",
                    "value": "Mary"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to set up dependencies to validate this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to solve these kinds of problems is to separate the complex validation from the rest of the schema using definitions and include it with an `allOf`. In this solution, I use implication to enforce the validation.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "rules": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/rule" }
    }
  },
  "required": ["rules"],
  "definitions": {
    "rule": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "precedence": { "type": "number", "minimum": 0 },
        "conditions": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/condition" }
        }
      },
      "required": ["precedence", "conditions"]
    },
    "condition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field": { "enum": ["Name", "Size"] },
        "relation": { "enum": ["is", "is not", "is not one of", "is one of"] },
        "value": { "type": ["array", "string", "number"] }
      },
      "required": ["field", "relation", "value"],
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/array-condition-implies-value-is-array" }]
    },
    "array-condition-implies-value-is-array": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/is-array-condition" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/value-is-array" }
      ]
    }
    "is-array-condition": {
      "properties": {
        "relation": { "enum": ["is not one of", "is one of"] }
      },
      "required": ["relation"]
    },
    "value-is-array": {
      "properties": {
        "value": { "type": "array" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! In `is-array-condition`, does the `required` property add something? Isn't the `relation` property already required by the `condition` definition?

Comment: tldr: It makes for better error messages. Longer answer: Without `required`, this condition can be true if the the relation is not present leading to requiring the type to be an array when it shouldn't. As you say, requiring it in the condition will cause the schema as a whole to fail whether it's present or not. So, keeping it in or not depends on whether or not you use the error messaging. I always include it any time I use the implication pattern.

Answer (score 8):

If you are able to use the latest draft-7 version of JSON Schema, you can use `if then else`, as per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.6

Although, using `oneOf` is also a valid approach, it might not be as clear to someone else inspecting your schema at a later date.

I've copied an example from an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/89211):

> If the "foo" property equals "bar", Then the "bar" property is
> required

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string" },
    "bar": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": { "enum": ["bar"] }
    }
  },
  "then": { "required": ["bar"] }
}
```

(You may want to check the draft support of the library you are using.)

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more concise way to do this, but this will work:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "Rules",
  "description": "Describes a set of rules",
  "definitions": {
    "field": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Name", "Size"]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "rules": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "precedence": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0
          },
          "conditions": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "properties": {
                    "field": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/field"
                    },
                    "relation": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "enum": ["is", "is not"]
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "type": ["string", "number"]
                    }
                  },
                  "required": ["field", "relation", "value"],
                  "additionalProperties": false
                },
                {
                  "properties": {
                    "field": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/field"
                    },
                    "relation": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "enum": ["is not one of", "is one of"]
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "type": ["array"]
                    }
                  },
                  "required": ["field", "relation", "value"],
                  "additionalProperties": false
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "required": ["precedence", "conditions"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["rules"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```