# JSON Schema dependencies: enum content depends on choice from another enum

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have an `enum` with a first set of choices, and a second `enum` whose content depends on the choice made in the first `enum`.

Here's a simple example of what I have at present (not right):

```
"fontGroup": {
    "title": "Font Group",
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
        "Roboto",
        "Noto",
        "Alegreya"
    ],
    "default": "Roboto"
},
"fontFamily": {
    "title": "Font Family",
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
        "Roboto Slab",
        "Roboto Condensed",
        "---",
        "Noto Sans",
        "Noto Serif",
        "---",
        "Alegreya SC",
        "Alegreya Sans"
    ],
    "default": "Roboto Slab"
}
```

Of course, if `Noto` is selected from the first `enum` then only the `Noto` related choices in the second `enum` are valid.  It is invalid to select `Noto` in combination with `Roboto Condensed`, for example.

How can this be specified in the schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)

Answer (score 1):

You can not refer to a relative property as of `draft-07` and below, but you can enumerate all possible object variations:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "fontGroup": {
          "const": "Roboto"
        },
        "fontFamily": {
          "enum": [
            "Roboto Slab",
            "Roboto Condenced"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "fontGroup": {
          "const": "Noto"
        },
        "fontFamily": {
          "enum": [
            "Noto Sans",
            "Noto Serif"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "fontGroup": {
          "const": "Alegreya"
        },
        "fontFamily": {
          "enum": [
            "Alegreya SC",
            "Alegreya Sans"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`const` keyword is not available in `draft-04`, you can change it to single-value enum: `"enum":["Roboto"]`.