# How can I validate a field in AJV only when either one of two fields is not empty

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajv

I'm trying to validate that a field is not empty only when either one of two fields is NOT empty using `ajv`.

E.g.

```
{ field1: '', field2: '2', field3: '' } // Invalid 
{ field1: '', field2: '', field3: '3' } // Invalid 
{ field1: '1', field2: '2', field3: '3' } // Valid 
{ field1: '', field2: '', field3: '' } // Valid
```

I'm trying to use this schema but I don't know how to specify the OR condition.

```
 {
  properties: {
    field1: {
      if: { properties: { field2: { minLength: 1 } },
      //or?
      then: {
          minLength: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I add an OR to this schema?

Comment: Take a look at this post, I think it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required specifically the `if` `then` `else` section.