# why my json schema let a wrong value pass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'm trying to validate a json object before requesting an api but I have an issue my `user` should look like

```
{
    "type": "student",
    "firstname": "jhon",
    "lastname": "DOE",
    "login": "jDOE",
    "pwd": "jdoepassword",
    "classes": []
}
```

or as a teacher

```
{
    "type": "teacher",
    "firstname": "teacher",
    "lastname": "TEACHER",
    "login": "tTEACHER",
    "pwd": "tTeacherpassword"
}
```

I'm trying to use ajv module and here's my code :

```js
var Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
const schema = {
  $jsonSchema: {
    anyOf: [
      {
        properties: {
          _id: {
            bsonType: 'objectId'
          },
          type: {
            'enum': [
              'student'
            ],
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'as to be a student'
          },
          firstname: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string'
          },
          lastname: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string'
          },
          login: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string',
            pattern: '^(?!$).*'
          },
          pwd: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string'
          },
          classes: {
            bsonType: 'array',
            items: {
              bsonType: [
                'string'
              ],
              additionalProperties: false
            }
          }
        },
        required: [
          'type',
          'firstname',
          'lastname',
          'login',
          'pwd',
          'classes'
        ],
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      {
        properties: {
          _id: {
            bsonType: 'objectId'
          },
          type: {
            'enum': [
              'teacher'
            ],
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'as to be a teacher'
          },
          firstname: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string'
          },
          lastname: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string'
          },
          login: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string',
            pattern: '^(?!$).*'
          },
          pwd: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            description: 'must be a string'
          }
        },
        required: [
          'type',
          'firstname',
          'lastname',
          'login',
          'pwd'
        ],
        additionalProperties: false
      }
    ]
  }
};
const test = ajv.compile(schema);
/* I initiate my command line app here so argv contains all needed fields */ 
let user = {};
user.type = argv.type || 'student';
user.firstname = argv.firstname;
user.lastname = argv.name;
user.login = argv.login || argv.firstname.slice(0, 1) + argv.name.slice(0, 7);
user.pwd = argv.password;
if (user.type == "student") user.classes = [];
const isValid = test(user);
if (isValid) {
    /* request API */
}
```

but when I create a user such as

```
{
  type: 'fujkdswghldfkj',   /*<= here's the important part*/
  firstname: 'arandomfirstname',
  lastname: 'arandomlasname',
  login: 'arandomlogin',
  pwd: 'password',
  classes: []
}
```

the api is requested as if it was normal to have a type "fujkdswghldfkj" instead of the enum 'student' or 'teacher', somebody know why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your schema definition is wrong. When I change it to:

```
const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    type: {
      enum: ['teacher', 'student']
    },
    firstname: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    lastname: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    login: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    pwd: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  },
  required: [
    'type',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'login',
    'pwd',
  ],
};
```

and then do the following:

```
const test = ajv.compile(schema);
const isValid = test({
  type: 'fujkdswghldfkj',   
  firstname: 'arandomfirstname',
  lastname: 'arandomlasname',
  login: 'arandomlogin',
  pwd: 'password',
  classes: [],
});
```

I get the following validation-error:

```
[
  {
    keyword: 'enum',
    dataPath: '.type',
    schemaPath: '#/properties/type/enum',
    params: { allowedValues: ["teacher", "student"] },
    message: 'should be equal to one of the allowed values'
  }
]
```

Comment: and how could I so to force the classes field to be only if the type is 'student' ?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest - maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340967/use-json-schema-to-require-or-disallow-properties-based-on-another-property-valu

Comment: I found this and wanted to share it https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html