# jsonSchema attribute conditionally required depends on parent object

Tags: validation, conditional-statements, jsonschema

Per this question [jsonschema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required), I can apply conditional required properties. However, it can only depend on the properties on the same level of object. In certain case, I want to one property required depend on its parent object property, is it possible? For the below example:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    { 
      os: { type: 'string', enum: ['macOs', 'windows'] },
      specs: {
        macModel: { 
          type: 'string', 
          enum: ['macbook air', 'macbook pro', 'macbook']
        },
        memory: { type: 'number' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to meet this requirement: **/spec/macModel** is required only when **/os** equals to **macOs**?

Comment: You can use the `if` `then` `else` keywords to achive this. http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.6 If the spec isn't enough to get you started, let me know =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the same approach applies. You just need to nest schemas a little deeper.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "os": { "enum": ["macOs", "windows"] },
    "specs": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "macModel": { "enum": ["macbook air", "macbook pro", "macbook"] },
        "memory": { "type": "number" }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/os-macOs-requires-macModel" }],
  "definitions": {
    "os-macOs-requires-macModel": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/os-macOs" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/requires-macModel" }
      ]
    },
    "os-macOs": {
      "properties": {
        "os": { "const": "macOs" }
      },
      "required": ["os"]
    },
    "requires-macModel": {
      "properties": {
        "specs": {
          "required": ["macModel"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that in the `/definitions/requires-macModel` schema it has to dig into the "specs" property and place the `required` there instead of at the top level as it is in the flat case.

I've used the implication pattern for this example, but the same approach can be taken with `if`-`then` if you prefer that approach and have access to a draft-07 validator.

Comment: It works, put the validation into allOf is a good pattern, thank you.