# Using if/then/else schema validation conditional on values in other json objects

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to use if/then/else to use three different schemas for an object, but based on the value of a JSON field outside of that object. I've only seen example of people making their conditionals based on fields within the same object.

Here's what I've tried:

```
schema: {

   'MyOtherObject': {
          '$id': '#/properties/MyOtherObject',
          'type': 'object',
          'additionalProperties': false,
          'title': 'The MyOtherObject Schema',
          'required': [
            'PaymentMethod'
          ],
          'properties': {
            'PaymentMethod': {
              '$id': '#/properties/Deal/properties/PaymentMethod',
              'type': 'string',
              'title': 'The PaymentMethod Schema',
              'default': '',
              'examples': [
                'Cash'
              ],
              'pattern': '^(.*)$'
            },
    ...
},

   'MyConditionalSchemaObject': {
          '$id': '#/properties/MyConditionalSchemaObject',
          'type': 'object',
          'additionalProperties': false,
          'title': 'The MyConditionalSchemaObject Schema',

          'if': {
            // Trying to get at the value above but don't know how... my schema validations still failing
            '2/MyOtherObject/properties/PaymentMethod' : { 'const': 'Cash' }
          },
          'then': {
            'required': [
              'PaymentStartDate'
            ],
            'properties': {
                'BankName': {
                  '$id': '#/properties/Financing/properties/BankName',
                  'type': ['string', 'null'],
                  'title': 'The Bankname Schema',
                  'default': '',
                  'examples': [
                    'Capital One Auto Finance'
                  ],

   ...

   }
}
```

I would expect that this code would check the value of the `PaymentMethod` field in the `MyOtherObject` json object and then use the schema based on passing the conditional check (if it equals `Cash`), but I'm still getting schema validation errors saying, `Should not be additional properties 'BankName'`, implying that the schema in the "then" block is not being used for validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required depends on parent object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203606/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required-depends-on-parent-object)

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I honestly can't make sense of the syntax from that answer. I'm trying to do this in the most readable, literal way using if-then-else.

Comment: Did you also look at the answer linked in that question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)? It fully describes the patterns in use. I suggest you read and understand that first. Then, go back and see if that answer makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the \`If\` \`then\` \`else\` condition in json schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539586/how-do-i-use-the-if-then-else-condition-in-json-schema)

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I also need something like this, as I am validating a postgres JSONB column, and I would like the json schema for that column to be able to refer to the values of other (non-JSONB) columns in the if-conditions, in order to conditionally validate the JSONB column. I need a separate schema for each JSONB column that I am validating, rather than a single schema that validates the entire row.

Comment: @HansBrende This is not possible. JSON Schema is designed to operate on one JSON instance at a time. There's no way to reference another instance from your schema. You can reference another schema, but not an instance.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I'm not saying it has to reference a _separate_ instance. It would suffice to reference the _same_ instance, but one level up, in the parent object. E.g. (rough pseudocode), {"if": {"properties": {reference_to_parent_object/"task_partition": {"const": "partitionA"}}}, "then": schema_for_this_object}

Comment: JSON Schema keywords can never access data up the hierarchy, only down. You have to move your `if`/`then` up to a level where it can access both values.

Comment: In other words, you can't have a schema per column and have conditionals that access multiple columns. The only way to access multiple columns is with a row-level schema.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers thanks for the feedback. Do you know if this this a philosophical limitation or is it simply that not enough people have made a feature request to go "up the hierarchy"? If nobody has yet, I've created a feature request for this [here](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/957#issuecomment-656814411).