# JSON Schema - Apply a definition to an array conditionally?

Tags: jsonschema

I need to apply a validation to an array, based on a property from a parent object. ex:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "account": {
            "type": "special"
        },
        "customers": [{
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "phoneNumbers": [
                "913 449-6602"
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

If account === 'special', then email and phoneNumbers need to be present inside customers. (email != null, and phoneNumbers.length > 1. no regex validation necessary)
else, i dont care.

I've sifted through dozens of previous questions and haven't found anything that solves this use case.

I am curious if applying a definition conditionally is possible? ex: Apply one definition when account.type is "special", another when it isn't. I don't think "If-then-contains" works, since I need the validation applied to ALL customers, not just one.

thanks in advance and let me know if more clarification needed.

relevant Q's that helped:

[jsonSchema attribute conditionally required depends on parent object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203606/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required-depends-on-parent-object)

[jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a condition to all items - just wrap it in the `items` keyword:

```
{
  "if": {
    "required": ["account"],
    "properties": {
      "account": {
        "required": ["type"],
        "properties": {
          "type": { "const": "special" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": ["customers"],
    "properties": {
      "customers": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
           ... check email and phoneNumbers here ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In pseudocode: if the account type is "special", then apply the extra definition to all customer items.

More info here:

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html
- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html

Comment: Thank you. this was clear and simple, exactly what i needed