# how write json schema to show a property based on another property value using json-editor?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm using [Json-editor](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor) for creating a page to edit a json schema.

I would like to set a property to be visible only if another property is set as `true`, for instance: property `has_pets` will rule the visibility of a `pets` array.

I was not able to find anything, only enforcing the validation field.

How can I write a schema definition to does not show a property based on another property value?

Comment: You can do this with the implication pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required/38781027#38781027

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)