# jsonschema enum values conditional on another enum value

Tags: jsonschema

I have a table of acceptable input combinations for my application:

```
noises   appearance
------   ----------
squeaks  fluffy
purrs    fluffy
hisses   fluffy
peeps    feathers
chirps   feathers
squeaks  feathers
hisses   scaly
```

No other combination of values is acceptable.

How can this be encoded in JSON Schema? The "rest of the schema" would look kind of like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["noise", "appearance"]
    "properties": {
      "noise": ...,
      "appearance": ...
    }
  }
```

Currently my application is using Draft 4 because it's what's supported by the last stable version of the [jsonschema package](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that there are a small and fixed number of options, I think the best thing is to enumerate all the options. The schema will be easier to read and maintain than the alternatives.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["noise", "appearance"],
    "properties": {
      ... any common properties ...
    },
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "noise": { "enum": ["squeaks"] },
          "appearance": { "enum": ["fluffy"] }
        }
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "noise": { "enum": ["purrs"] },
          "appearance": { "enum": ["fluffy"] }
        }
      },
      ... other combinations ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: To see the alternatives I mentioned, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required/38781027#38781027, especially the "Implication" method.