# How to emulate a switch statement (switch-case) in a JSON Schema?

Tags: validation, switch-statement, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm using a JSON Schema[`jsonschema`](https://json-schema.org/) to validate JSON records. Here's an example schema. It has only two cases here, but imagine a similar scenario where it instead has a hundred cases laid out like these.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "properties": {
          "a": {"type": "integer", "enum": [0]},
          "b": {"type": "integer", "enum": [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]},
          "c": {"type": "string", "enum": ["always the same"]}
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "properties": {
          "a": {"type": "integer", "enum": [1]},
          "b": {"type": "integer", "enum": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]},
          "c": {"type": "string", "enum": ["always the same"]}
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

The key issue is the duplication of the `"c"` field. I'd like to be able to switch-case on `"a"`, validating for a corresponding `"b"`, but having `"c"` always remain the same. I don't want to have to spell out `"c"` a hundred different times. Is this possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. In fact, it's good practice to only put in `anyOf`/`oneOf` the parts that change.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "c": { "const": "always the same" }
  },
  "required": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "a": { "const": 0 },
        "b": { "enum": [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "a": { "const": 1 },
        "b": { "enum": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: With draft-7, you can also use `const` rather than an enum with a single value.

Comment: Ah yes, I cleaned up some things, but I missed that one. `const` was added in draft-06 for anyone who needs to know.

Comment: Can I ask why you would choose to use `anyOf` rather than `oneOf` in this case? I can see that `anyOf` would work just fine since the defining property only has one value, but it seems like `oneOf` would be less error prone since it would require that the value of `a` is different in each subschema.

Comment: @Vorticity `anyOf` can be evaluated more efficiently by a validator. With `anyOf`, the validator can stop evaluating the `anyOf` schemas once it finds a match (in can short-circuit). With `oneOf`, the validator has to check every schema in `oneOf` to ensure that one and only one of the schemas match. In cases like this where the schemas are mutually exclusive, `oneOf` is doing unnecessary work.

Comment: In any case, I discourage this pattern these days in favor of `if`/`then`/`else` which is more efficient and will produce better error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/1320693

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement doesn't exist in JSON Schema. There was a long discussion about a proposal for it [here](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/64). Without it, there are a couple of possible ways to provide this functionality:

### anyOf / oneOf

The solution suggested by Jason Desrosiers will do the job but with a couple of caveats:

1. You can only have a "default" case by manually constructing it with the other possible values. For the example in Jason's answer, this might look something like this:

```
      "properties": {
        "a": { "not": { "enum": [0, 1] } },
        "b": { "enum": [10, 11, 12] }
      }
```

2. If using `oneOf`, care is needed to make sure all cases are mutually exclusive and cannot overlap.

### if...then

Personally, I prefer a set of `if...then` fragments (surrounded by an `allOf`) instead. This has the same caveats as above. One advantage is it makes it clear which property is being "switched" on. Another is if using a validator such as [ajv](https://ajv.js.org/), the validation messages received when the JSON fails validation will pinpoint the issue better. If an `anyOf` or `oneOf` is used, you will simply get a validation message that the whole thing hasn't been met, which makes the cause less clear. But using `if` fragments, you are told which one hasn't been met and why. Here is Jason's example converted into this syntax:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "c": { "const": "always the same" }
  },
  "required": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "a": { "const": 0 },
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "b": { "enum": [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "a": { "const": 1 },
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "b": { "enum": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```