# how to set the type of a schema object based on the value of another property?

Tags: jsonschema

I have an object (from a 3rd party, so I can't change it) that have a property named "key", and another property called "value" that is optional, and it's type depends on the value of the "key" property.

For instance:
If the key is "comment", the type of value `{"Text":"commentValue"}`.
If the key is "offset", the type of value is `{"seconds":int}`.
If the key is "weather", the type of value is `{"value": Enum["sun", "clouds", "rain"...]}`

Moreover, some of the keys do not have the value property, so the schema should forbid it from appearing with these keys. one of these keys is "standby" (as you can see in my current attempt below)

I've tried manipulating the code samples from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/3094533), but couldn't make it work.

I'm currently attempting to validate output json against my schema attempts using [Newtonsoft's JSON Schema Validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) - but I can't seem to get the "value" property defined correctly.

This is my code so far:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "TestOptionalObject",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "test"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "test": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/test"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "test": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "key",
            ],
            "properties": {
                "key": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["standby", "comment", "offset"]
                },
                "value" : {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                          "key": {"enum": ["comment"]}
                        }
                    },
                    "then": { 
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/commentValue"
                    },
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                          "key": {"enum": ["offset"]}
                        }
                    },
                    "then": { 
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/offsetValue"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "commentValue" : {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "text",
            ],
            "properties": {
                "text" : {"type" : "string"}
            }
        },
        "offsetValue" : {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "seconds",
            ],
            "properties": {
                "seconds" : {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error messages I get:

> JSON does not match schema from 'then'.
>   Schema path: #/definitions/offsetValue/then
>
> Property 'text' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path: #/definitions/offsetValue/additionalProperties
>
> Required properties are missing from object: seconds.
>   Schema path: #/definitions/offsetValue/required

Json examples to validate:

Should fail:

```
{
  "test": {
    "key": "comment",
      "value": {"seconds":12}
  }
}


{
  "test": {
    "key": "standby",
     "value": {"asdf":12}
  }
}
```

Should pass:

```
{
  "test": {
    "key": "comment",
     "value": {"text":"comment text"}
  }
}


{
  "test": {
    "key": "offset",
     "value": {"seconds":12}
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to test this, but I'm 99% sure the issue you have here is you have multiple `if/then` statements in the same object. Remember, the behaviour of a JSON object which has duplicate keys is undefined. You can either wrap each pair in an `allOf`, or use the `else` keyword and define the next schema inside that.

Comment: putting the second `if` inside the `else` of the first one was a partial success - I've successfully validated a json with `comment` key but failed to validate a json with `offset` key. Will try the `allOf` and report.

Comment: Nesting `if/then/else` gets annoying if you have many checks to do. `oneOf` may be faster if your library of choice short-circuits.

Comment: Couldn't get oneOf or allOf to work properly. The schema is valid but it passes invalid json outputs as valid...

Comment: Can you simplify your new JOSN Schema and JSON instance and update your question to include please? I can then help. Give example of data that should pass and should fail.

Comment: @Relequestual I'm not sure how to simplify the schema, so I've left it as is, but I've added sample jsons that should pass or fail. Note: the one with the key "standby" should have no value property at all. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I can immediately see some problems. Try your schema and instances using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net and see if you can sort out the issues. Initially, `seconds` causes validation to fail because `additionalProperties` is false for the `test` object.

Comment: I've already tested it with jsonschemavalidator.net... and the seconds is a property of the `value` object, not of the `test` object, so as far as I understand it should not be a problem...

Comment: I'm looking at the first example instance that you say should pass. Otherwise, your provided instances pass and fail as expected.

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo. fixed.

Comment: Right, I can see what you've done / overlooked. There are a few issues in your schema creation. I'll have to wait a bit before I can restructure this, but I can see what you want and why it's not working. =] Expect something in about 1 hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your JSON Schema so it does what you expect, apart form key of `standby` as you didn't include that in your schema, and you should be able to replicate the pattern I've created to add new keys as required.

The major issue you had was a false assumption about where to place `if/then/else` keywords. They are applicator keywords, and so must be applied to the object which you are checking the condition of, and not a `properties` key value. Because you were using `if/then/else` in the object which was a value of `value`, you were applying `if/then/else` to the value of `value` rather than `test`.

You needed your `if` to apply to `test` to get the correct scope for checking the `key` property value.

Here is the resulting fixed schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "TestOptionalObject",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "test"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/test"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "test": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "key"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "standby",
            "comment",
            "offset"
          ]
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "comment"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/commentValue"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "offset"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/offsetValue"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "commentValue": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "text"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "offsetValue": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "seconds"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "seconds": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want any more help, please feel free to join the JSON Schema slack using the discussion link on the http://json-schema.org site.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it's something simple that I'm missing.... Just one more thing is needed for this to be perfect for my needs - when the key is "standby", the validation should fail if the json output contains the "value" property.

Comment: You can do this by adding another `if/then` block, where the `then` schema is: properties -> value -> false

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've probably saved me a day of work on this!

Comment: I'll know where to come if I have an SQL issue ;) You're welcome! =]

Answer (score 1):

> If the key is "comment", the type of value {"Text":"commentValue"}.
> If the key is "offset", the type of value is {"seconds":int}.
> If the key is "weather", the type of value is {"value": Enum["sun", "clouds", "rain"...]}

This is a classic case of discriminated union, so can be expressed like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "const": "comment"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "Text": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "const": "offset"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "seconds": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "const": "weather"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "enum": ["sun", "clouds", "rain"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "enum": ["standby"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It can probably be simplified further, but you get the idea.
Generally avoid using fancy JSON Schema features which don't map directly to basic type systems unless you absolutely have to. The whole point of JSON Schema is to represent serializable data in readable form both for machines and humans, not map the type system of the language running the server into JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though too late for me to test it I'm pretty sure someone might find it useful in the future.