# Update a boolean type value based on value of another property

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following json schema. My plan is to set the value of *notifyApprover* to true or false depending on the value of *AutoApprove*. How can i do this ? I am new to JSON schemas.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "properties": {
    "AutoApprove": {
      "title": "Auto Approve",
      "type": "boolean"     
    },
      "notifyApprover": {
      "title": "Notify Approver",
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881623/how-to-set-the-type-of-a-schema-object-based-on-the-value-of-another-property) which is helpful, just not sure how to implement it for my requirements.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you show us your best attempt, we can give you an answer that addresses where you went wrong rather than just giving you the answer.

Comment: Also, you might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required/38781027#38781027 to be a valuable reference.