# Conditional check in JSON schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have following JSON schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "Payload": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Person": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "Id",
                            "Name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Reference": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Status": {
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "Passed": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Failed": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Status": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "Reference"
            ],
            "not": {
                "required": [
                    "Payload"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "properties": {
                "Status": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "Passed"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "Reference"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to check if JSON message has status failed then person array should not be present.
It should be present only if status is passed.

I tried following [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required) but definitely i am doing something wrong as validator passes with Failed status and person details present. Can someone tell what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the json you're validating against?

Comment: You're using draft-4 of JSON Schema. `required` is different for draft-4 than for the most recent draft. Although without seeing the data you're trying to validate, I can't tell if that's the only issue here.

Comment: I would guess you have a number of issues. Are you able to migrate to using draft-7?

Comment: @Relequestual Regarding `required`, I think you're thinking of draft-03. `required` is the same in draft-04 as it is today.

Comment: Migrating to Draft 7 would not be possible :(

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers your solution and clarifications helped.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers Right you are! I need to get that right! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues.

**/properties/Reference/properties/Status**

This isn't a valid schema. It looks like you're trying to describe an enum.

**additionalProperties**

The reason is complicated, but the conditional patterns don't work with `additionalProperties`. The good news is it's also unnecessary. You can just leave those out.

**/anyOf**

Looks like you're using the "Enum" pattern, but the implication pattern is better in this case because only one of the enum states has additional constraints.

**Conditional on nested property**

Your schemas that define the `Reference.Status` value are actually just pointing to `Status`. You need a schema that describes the parent property as well.

---

The following does what I think your schema was trying to do.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Payload": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Person": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "Id": { "type": "string" },
              "Name": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["Id", "Name"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Reference": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Status": { "enum": ["Passed", "Failed"] }
      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "not": {
        "properties": {
          "Reference": {
            "properties": {
              "Status": { "enum": ["Failed"] }
            },
            "required": ["Status"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["Reference"]
      }
    },
    { "not": { "required": ["Payload"] } }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)The comments and snippet really helped me out. The actual schema was a bit different and I had created  new schema to explain the case due to which /properties/Reference/properties/Status came in. I will correct the question later.