# How to require a property B when a boolean property A is true

Tags: json, jsonschema

Using JSON Schema, how can I specify that property `bar` is required when property `foo` (a `boolean`) is set to `true`?

I've tried the following:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "boolean" },
    "bar": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": { "boolean": true }
    },
    "required": ["foo"]
  },
  "then": { "required": ["bar"] }
}
```

However, this fails to validate:

```
{
  "foo": false
}
```

because it seems `bar` is still required despite `foo` being `false`:

```
Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: bar.
Schema path:
    #/then/required
```

I've also tried this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "boolean" },
    "bar": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": { "const": "true" }
    },
    "required": ["foo"]
  },
  "then": { "required": ["bar"] }
}
```

But this accepts the following JSON, which should be considered invalid:

```
{
  "foo": true
}
```

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/5380), but it uses type `string` for `foo`, which works fine. I need `foo` to be `boolean`.

### How can I stipulate that `bar` is required when `foo` is `true`?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is a simple typo sort of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were SO CLOSE to getting this right.

Your use of `const` was correct, but the value is a string as opposed to a boolean value. You want...

`"foo": { "const": true }`

[Live demo](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEAXAngBwKasiiAPYBGAVjgMZqoA0CyqWATkbs2gJY5j6JxJkhAGZEifYIUy4+qEmIA2OAIbxUiAL71BjECWXMJU7HiiEwaZp3gBzdRoabtuzsImPdLNjg7deZgSEhVFFxAMJKIngLPksAVxxNDydk1GYcAEc4znSAEz4AbRCxVABdRy1HVDQACxw1cLTM7LzCuQMypPgNEFoQTigYKpBQvmFlBTA8bpANIA)