# best way to make conditional arrays in json schema with decent error messages

Tags: arrays, tuples, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I would like to constrain a (tuple) array in JSON-schema, and get decent error messages but so far I was unsuccessful.

The array consists of 2 items, the first is a string, and the second is an object. The properties that are allowed/required in the object depends on the string.
2 valid examples would be:

```
{
    "color": [ "white", { "a white property": 42 }]
}
```

and

```
{
    "color": [ "black", { "this is a black property": "tAttUQoLtUaE" }]
}
```

for reference, the type in typescript would be defined as:

```
type MyObject = {
    color:
    | ["white", {
        "a white property": number
    }]
    | ["black", {
        "this is a black property": string
    }]
}
```

I have tried 'oneOf' (see below), and it works, but if the file is not valid, the error message is uncomprehensible.
You can try this instance at jsonschemavalidator.org:

```
{
  "color": [ "black", {
      "XXX": "foo"
  }]
}
```

My attempt:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "color"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "color": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "enum": [ "white"]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": [ "a white property" ],
                            "additionalProperties": false,
                            "properties": {
                                "a white property": {
                                    "type": "number"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "enum": ["black"]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": [ "this is a black property" ],
                            "additionalProperties": false,
                            "properties": {
                                "this is a black property": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Is there a better way to express this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required/38781027#38781027), for a description of four strategies for conditional constraints. Here they are in order of which strategy produces the best error messages.

1. **`dependencies`**: This is a very specific constraint, so it tends to have great error messages. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in your situation.
2. **`if`/`then`**: This is going produce the best messages in your case.
3. **Implication**: This produces pretty good error messages, but not quite as good as `if`/`then`. `if`/`then` was added in draft-07. If you can't use draft-07 or higher, this is your best bet.
4. **Enum**: This is the one you are using and it produces awful errors as you have seen. This is the worst option for error messaging.