# JSON schema validation of conditional array objects

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I have two type of datasets, with csv or fixed length data. In csv data the fieldlist is just a list of names, 
while in fixed length data each field is specified by fieldName and fieldLength.
I need a json schema to validate both cases, but after trying several solutions, including 
 [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required), I am not sure it can be done. Or maybe my understanding of JSON schema is still far from perfect.

json :

```
{
      "dataset": "csv data",
      "dataFormat": "csv",
      "fieldList": [{
                  "fieldName": "id"
            },
            {
                  "fieldName": "num"
            },
            {
                  "fieldName": "struct"
            }
      ]
}

{
    "dataset": "fixed length",
    "dataFormat": "fixed",
    "fieldList": [{
            "fieldName": "id",
            "fieldLength": 13
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "num"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "struct"
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "dataset",
    "dataFormat",
    "fieldList"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "dataset": {
      "$id": "#/properties/dataset",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataFormat": {
      "$id": "#/properties/dataFormat",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "csv",
        "fixed"
      ]
    },
    "fieldList": {
      "$id": "#/properties/fieldList",
      "type": "array",
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/fieldList/items",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": true,
        "required": [
          "fieldName"
        ],
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "dataFormat": {
              "const": "fixed"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {"items":{
          "required": [
            "fieldLength"
          ]}
        },
        "properties": {
          "fieldName": {
            "$id": "#/properties/fieldList/items/properties/fieldName",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "fieldLength": {
            "$id": "#/properties/fieldList/items/properties/fieldLength",
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both documents are positively validated, even if in the "fixed" type only the first item includes the required fieldLength.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things in your schema that can be improved:

1. The `if`/`then` is in the wrong place. Right now, the `if` looks for a `"dataFormat"` property inside the `"fieldList"` `items` and never finds one. The `then` likewise tries to enforce the existence of a `"fieldLength"` property in `"fieldList".items.items` (and since `"fieldList".items` is an `object` and not an `array`, that would simply be ignored.
2. You should remove the `additionalItems` attribute. To quote [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html):

   > When `items` is a single schema, the `additionalItems` keyword is meaningless, and it should not be used.
3. You can remove the `additionalProperties` attribute, since its default value is already `true`. Another quote from [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties):

   > The `additionalProperties` keyword is used to control the handling of extra stuff, that is, `properties` whose names are not listed in the properties keyword. By default any additional properties are allowed.
4. The `$id` attributes are not adding much value (and are not compatible with the newer Draft 2019-09, where they would only be allowed in the new `$anchor` keyword). You may want to omit those.

---

Your main issue is point #1 here.
You should be able to achieve what you want by adding something like this at the top level:

```
"oneOf": [
  {
    "properties": {
      "dataFormat": { "const": "csv" }
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "dataFormat": { "const": "fixed" },
      "fieldList": {
        "items": {
          "required": ["fieldLength"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The complete schema could look like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "dataset",
    "dataFormat",
    "fieldList"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "dataset": {
      "$id": "#/properties/dataset",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataFormat": {
      "$id": "#/properties/dataFormat",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "csv",
        "fixed"
      ]
    },
    "fieldList": {
      "$id": "#/properties/fieldList",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/fieldList/items",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "fieldName"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "fieldName": {
            "$id": "#/properties/fieldList/items/properties/fieldName",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "fieldLength": {
            "$id": "#/properties/fieldList/items/properties/fieldLength",
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "dataFormat": {
          "const": "csv"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "dataFormat": {
          "const": "fixed"
        },
        "fieldList": {
          "items": {
            "required": [
              "fieldLength"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

For completeness sake: you can achieve the same with `if`/`then` as well:

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "dataFormat": {
      "const": "fixed"
    }
  }
},
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "fieldList": {
      "items": {
        "required": [
          "fieldLength"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solutions works fine ! Unfortunately my use case is a little bit more complex than the one present in my question: the dataset is an array, each item with its own fieldlist. I tried to adapt your "oneOf" solution by adding dataset/items before the fieldlist but with no success...

Comment: @mre maybe add that via an edit to the bottom of your question and I can try to assist you with that as well

Comment: @mre you'd have to add `dataset`/`items`/`properties` before `fieldList` I'd imagine. Don't forget that last `properties`.

Comment: Thanks again @Carsten, that last `properties` did the trick, everything is working now !!!