# Json Schema Dependencies with Object Definitions

Tags: json, jsonschema

When using json schema 7 is it possible to set a dependency on an object definition references rather individual fields?

For example I have a type string and properties object. Depending on the type the properties object fields will be different but I don't want to set dependancy of every possible field. That's rather tedious e.g.

```
{
  "$id": "https://sibytes.datagovernor.com/dataset.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "dataset",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "dataset_type": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": ""
    },
    "dataset_properties": {
      << BASICALLY HERE I WANT THE REFERENCE OBJECT DEFINITION TO BE DEPENDENT ON THE DATASET TYPE ABOVE>>
      "$ref": "http://example.com/tableproperties.schema.json"
      "$ref": "http://example.com/tableproperties.fileproperties.json"
      ...there will be others.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/5127499)

Comment: No.. I want to conditionally drop in a different entire object definitions based on the value of data_set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out this can de done using sub-schema's and predicates
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

```
{
  "$id": "https://sibytes.datagovernor.com/dataset.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "dataset",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {

    "dataset_type": {
      "enum": ["Table","View"],
      "description": "This is the type of physical object that the dataset describes."
    }
  },
  "dataset_properties": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {"dataset_type":{"const": "Table"}}
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "dataset_properties" : {
              "$ref": "dataset.table.schema.json#/definitions/dataset_properties"
            }
          }
        }
      },

      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {"dataset_type":{"const": "View"}}
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "dataset_properties" : {
              "$ref": "dataset.view.schema.json#/definitions/dataset_properties"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "required": ["dataset_type","dataset_properties"]
}
```