# JSON Schema switch object properties based on enum

Tags: jsonschema

I've been struggling with "switch" in JSON Schema. Went through couple of GitHub and SO discussions on this topic but haven't find solution.
My intention is to vary "payload" object properties based on "id" enum that will have 30 different mappings ("payload" definitions per enum "id").
For example first message json object will have amount and other properties but for the demo purpose let's go only with one property (amout):

```
{
"message": {
    "id": 1,
    "correlationId": "a0011e83-280e-4085-b0f1-691059aaae61",
    "payload": {
        "amount": 100
    }
}
```

}

And second json:

```
{
"message": {
    "id": 2,
    "correlationId": "a0011e83-280e-4085-b0f1-691059aaae61",
    "payload": {
        "code": "xyz"
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to build JSON Schema (draft 7 or any other) in this manner?

Comment: What’s wrong with having a big `oneOf` in the `message` schema? Each `oneOf` would include the `"id": { "const": 1 }` and the respective `payload` schema’s `properties`. There are a couple of examples also here on SO.

Comment: @Carsten So basically you are proposing something like this: `{
 "message": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["subject"],
      "oneOf": [
        {"properties": {"subject": {"const": 1}}}, {"properties": {"payload": {"$ref": "#/definitions/payload1"}}},
        {"properties": {"subject": {"const": 2}}}, {"properties": {"payload": {"$ref": "#/definitions/payload2"}}},
      ],
      "definitions": {
        "payload1": {
          "amount": "number"
        },
        "payload2": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      }
    }
}`

Comment: The given schema is not quite right yet (just hard to correct via the phone now), but that’s the rough direction yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is a fairly common requirement. Using `oneOf`/`anyOf` should get you where you want.

In those cases where the alternatives are mutually exclusive (due to the different "id" values), I'm in favour of `anyOf` to allow Schema Validator to stop checking when encountering the first matching subschema – whereas `oneOf` implies that all other alternatives must not match, e.g. in case of `"id": 1` a validator would only have to check against the first subschema in an `anyOf` to indicate that it is valid while for `oneOf` it'd have to check against the other 29 to ensure that those aren't also valid. But you may find `oneOf` more expressive for human consumers of your schema.

For your particular scenario, I'd imagine something along the lines of the following schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["message"],
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["id", "correlationId", "payload"],
      "properties": {
        "id": { "enum": [1, 2, 3] },
        "correlationId": { "type": "string" },
        "payload": { "type": "object" }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "id": { "const": 1 },
            "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payload1" }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "id": { "const": 2 },
            "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payload2" }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "id": { "const": 3 },
            "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payload3" }
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "payload1": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["amount"],
      "properties": {
        "amount": { "type": "integer" }
      }
    },
    "payload2": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["code"],
      "properties": {
        "code": { "type": "string" }
      }
    },
    "payload3": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["foo"],
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the first building block but it was important for me to understand it so I can reuse it in deeper (nested) levels.