# In jsonschema specific field is required based on value of another field?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have mentioned two scenarios below, for which i want to generate a jsonschema. If the `color` value is `red` then  `redQuote` will be the required filed in the jsonschema. If it is `black` then `blackQuote` be the required filed. So required filed of the jsonschema is depend on color value. how we can use `if'/'then'/'else'` keywords, or `'dependencies'` in draft-07 and `'dependentRequired' in draft2019-09` in this case?.

Example-1

```
{
 "color": "red",
  "quote": {
                "is_apply": True,
               "redQuote": "something"
               }
}
```

Example-2

```
{
 "color": "black",
  "quote": {
                 "is_apply": True,
               "blackQuote": "something"
               }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "color": {"const": "red"},
                "quote":{
                    "properties":{
                        "is_apply": {"type": "boolean"}
                    },
                    "required": ["redQuote"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "color": {"const": "black"},
                "quote":{
                    "properties":{
                        "is_apply": {"type": "boolean"}
                    },
                    "required": ["blackQuote"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It worked for me. Feel free to comment if there are any other way to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want `allOf` there. You've created a schema which will only successfully validate an empty object.

Comment: @Relequestual Good catch anyOf is required instead of allOf.