# JSON schema - new sub schema based on a property

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema

I wanted a JSON schema that could have 3 fields: `num`, `key1`, and `key2`. Both `num` and `key1` are mandatory fields. The field `key2` is mandatory ONLY WHEN the `key1` was provided a value of **'abc'**. Here is the schema that I have created:

```js
schema = {
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
        num: {
            type: 'number',
            minimum: 1,
            maximum: 5
        },
        key1: {
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['abc', 'def']
        }
    },
    required: ['num', 'key1'],
    if: {
        properties: {
            key1: {
                const: 'abc'
            }
        }
    },
    then: {
        properties: {
            key2: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the `instance` that I want to validate against the `schema` using npm module **jsonscehma** (`"jsonschema": "^1.2.0"`):

```js
instance = {
    num: 1,
    key1: 'abc'
};

var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
var v = new Validator();

console.log(v.validate(instance, schema));
```

My expectation here is that, since the value of `key1` is **'abc'**, this should ideally throw an error saying

> mandatory field "key2" is missing

But, there is no such error in this case.

Also, if I provide `key2` in the instance, I am getting

> additionalProperty "key2" exists in instance when not allowed

even though, `key1` is **'abc'**.

Please specify if I have missed anything here.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using only supports draft-04 of the specification.

`if` / `then` / `else` wasn't added till draft-07.

Comment: Which version is 'draft-07'?

Comment: `jsonschema` is an npm package. It looks like it only supports SOME of draft-04. If you want `draft-07` support, you'll need to look for a new library.

Comment: @SreekarMouli if you are stuck with draft-04, you can use the Implication Pattern to get the same behavior as `if`/`then`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required/38781027#38781027. But, you're better off choosing a different JSON Schema implementation that supports more recent drafts. Two options are ajv and hyperjump/json-schema.