# json schema validation does not work for dependencies?

Tags: json, yaml, schema, jsonschema

As far as I understand, using:

```
    dependencies:
      cake:
        - eggs
        - flour
```

in a JSON schema validation (I actually parse the schema in YAML, but it should not really matter) should forbid the presence of a cake without an entry for eggs and flour. So this should be rejected:

```
receip:
  cake: crepes
```

while this should be accepted:

```
receip:
  eggs: 3 eggs, given by farmer
  flour: 500g
  cake: crepes
```

Unfortunately, both cases are accepted in my case. Any idea what I made wrong? I also tried to add another level `required` as proposed by [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required) but the problem is the same.

**MWE**
In case it helps, here are all the files that I'm using.

`debug_schema.yml`:

```
$schema: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema
type: object
properties:
  receip:
    type: object
    properties:
      eggs:
        type: string
      flour:
        type: string
      cake:
        type: string
    dependencies:
      cake:
        - eggs
        - flour
```

b.yml:

```
receip:
  ## I'd like to forbid a cake without eggs and flour
  ## Should not validate until I uncomment:
  # eggs: 3 eggs, given by farmer
  # flour: 500g
  cake: crepes
```

`validate_yaml.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml
from jsonschema import validate, ValidationError
import argparse

# Instantiate the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This tool not only checks if the YAML file is correct in term'
                                 + ' of syntex, but it also checks if the structure of the YAML file follows'
                                 + ' the expectations of this project (e.g. that it contains a list of articles,'
                                 + ' with each articles having a title etc…).')
# Optional argument
parser.add_argument('--schema', type=str, default="schema.yml",
                    help='Path to the schema')

parser.add_argument('--yaml', type=str, default="science_zoo.yml",
                    help='Path to the YAML file to verify')

args = parser.parse_args()

class YAMLNotUniqueKey(Exception):
    pass


# By default, PyYAML does not raise an error when two keys are identical, which is an issue here
# see https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/165#issuecomment-430074049
class UniqueKeyLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
        mapping = set()
        for key_node, value_node in node.value:
            key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
            if key in mapping:
                raise YAMLNotUniqueKey(f"Duplicate key {key!r} found.")
            mapping.add(key)
        return super().construct_mapping(node, deep)
    
with open(args.schema, "r") as schema_stream:
    try:
        schema = yaml.load(schema_stream, UniqueKeyLoader)
        with open(args.yaml, "r") as yaml_stream:
            try: 
                validate(yaml.load(yaml_stream, UniqueKeyLoader), schema)
                print("The YAML file is correct and follows the schema, congrats! :D")
            except ValidationError as exc:
                print(exc.message)
                print("The problem is located in the JSON at the path {}.".format(exc.json_path))
            except YAMLNotUniqueKey as exc:
                print("ERROR: {}".format(exc))
                print("Rename in the YAML one the two instances of this key to ensure all keys are unique.")
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print("Errors when trying to load the YAML file:")
                print(exc)

    except YAMLNotUniqueKey as exc:
        print("ERROR: {}".format(exc))
        print("Rename in the schema one the two instances of this key to ensure all keys are unique.")
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print("Errors when trying to load the schema file:")
        print(exc)
```

Command:

```
./validate_yaml.py --yaml b.yml --schema debug_schema.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so it seems that this keyword has [been deprecated](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/object.html#dependencies), and split into `dependentRequired` (see e.g. [this example](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/object.html#dependentrequired)) and `dependentSchemas` (see e.g. [this example](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/object.html#dependentschemas)). Just using `dependentRequired` solves the issue:

```
$schema: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema
type: object
properties:
  receip:
    type: object
    properties:
      eggs:
        type: string
      flour:
        type: string
      cake:
        type: string
    dependentRequired:
      cake:
        - eggs
        - flour
```