# JSON schema conditionally required based on the value of a key from another object

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON object as blow:

```
{
  "a": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": true
  },
  "b": {
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4" // make key4 required if the value of key2 is true, otherwise it should be optional
  }
}
```

What I need is to make key4 required if the value of key2 is true, otherwise it should be optional.
I know that [JSON schema support optional required based on the value of keys within the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required). But in this case, what I need to base on the value of a key from another object.

---

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works the same way as it does with a flat structure. The `if` and `then` keywords are just schemas that apply to the instance. So, if you want to define nested conditions or nested constraints you just need to define a schema that expresses those constraints.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "properties": {
          "key2": { "const": true }
        },
        "required": ["key2"]
      }
    },
    "required": ["a"]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "b": { "required": ["key4"] }
    }
  }
}
```