# JSON Schema to compare & validate dependent attributes from different scope

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, azure-logic-app-standard

I have following JSON structure

```
{
    "customFields": {
        "paymentMethods": [
            {
                "tokenizedCard": "11223",
                "cardNumber": "XXXXXX001"
            },
            {
                "tokenizedCard": "12345",
                "cardNumber": "XXXXX678"
            }
        ]
    },
    "paymentDetails": {
        "method": [
            {
                "paymentType": "CREDIT_CARD",
                "tokenizedCard": "11223"
            },
            {
                "paymentType": "UPI",
                "tokenizedCard": "12345"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to validate this JSON with following condition.

```
If paymentDetails.method.paymentType = CREDIT_CARD then
    compare tokenizedCard from same object with the tokenizedCard of customFields.paymentMethods and if matches then make cardNumber required from that object of customFields.paymentMethods.
```

I tried using $ref & $definition and but I was not able to make that happen.

Any help with the required schema would be appreciated!

Note: I am doing schema validation in azure logic app.

Comment: You might want to show us your schema and what you’ve done.

Comment: Depending on what JSON Schema features Azure supports, you'll either want `if`/`then` or the Implication Pattern from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required

Answer (score 0):

**Using variables and condition action, you can achieve the scenario**.

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Passing the Json in Http request trigger as shown below,
  [image]
- Initialized three variables for tokenizedCard of paymentDetails, tokenizedCard of paymentMethods and cardNumber of paymentMethods.
  [image]
- Next taken a for each loop and passed input as **triggerBody()?['paymentDetails']?['method']**
  [image]
- Next taken a condition action and used expression **items('For_each')?['paymentType']** is equal to **CREDIT_CARD**
  [image]
- In true block added actions as shown below,
  [image]
- For comparing tokenizedCard added another for each loop and passed input as **triggerBody()?['customFields']?['paymentMethods']**
- Next set variable for tokenizedCard. One is for paymentDetails and other is for paymentMethods.
  [image]
- Next taken another condition action to compare two tokenizedCards.
  [image]
- If both are matching then getting card number value as shown below,
  [image]
- Tested logic app and able to get card number,
  [image]

Output of getting card number:
[image]