# How specify dependencies in Json Schema using definition references?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON schema that I am using to validate my API input as shown below. I want to define a dependency where if `testMetricsConfig.humanTestMetrics` are provided then `humanTestAdditionalConfig` should be required. How can I do that?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Expected request schema for the Test operation.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "testMetricsConfig": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/testMetricsConfig"
        },
        "humanTestAdditionalConfig": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/humanTestAdditionalConfig"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "testMetricsConfig"
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "testMetricsConfig": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "automatedTestMetricsConfig": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "maxItems": 10,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/automatedTestMetric"
                    }
                },
                "humanTestMetricsConfig": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "maxItems": 10,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/humanTestMetric"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "automatedTestMetric": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "metricName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+$",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "maxLength": 64
                },
                "datasets": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "maxItems": 6,
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "metricName",
                "datasets"
            ]
        },
        "humanTestMetric": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "metricName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+$",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "maxLength": 64
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "^.+$",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "maxLength": 100
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "metricName"
            ]
        },
        "humanTestAdditionalConfig": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "testInstructions": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at a bunch of questions but nothing seems to be solving this particular dependency checks.

I have tried adding the `dependencies`, as follow for the `testMetricsConfig` object:

```
"testMetricsConfig": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "automatedTestMetricsConfig": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "maxItems": 10,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/automatedTestMetric"
                    }
                },
                "humanTestMetricsConfig": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "maxItems": 10,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/humanTestMetric"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "humanTestMetricsConfig": ["humanTestAdditionalConfig"]
            }
        }
```

But doing this expects me to add the `humanTestAdditionalConfig` within the `humanTestMetricsConfig` object which is not what I want. I want something like this.

```
{
    "testMetricsConfig": {
        "humanTestMetricsConfig": [{
          "metricName": "someTest"
        }]
    },
    "humanTestAdditionalConfig": {
      "testInstructions": "perform the test"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required