# JSON Schema oneOf inside of allOf with If Then Conditional Statements

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am making a JSON Schema using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and https://jsonschema.dev/ to validate them and both are giving me the same problem and idk what is wrong

Here is the JSON that I am using

```json
{
  "Cdtr": {
    "Id": {
      "PrvtId": {
        "Othr": {
          "Id": "123456"
          "SchmeNm": {
            "Cd": "NIDN"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the JSON Schema

```json
    {
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "SchmeNm": {
                                                        "Cd": {
                                                            "enum": [
                                                                "NIDN",
                                                                "CCPT",
                                                                "ANRU"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "Id": {
                                                        "maxLength": 8,
                                                        "minLength": 6,
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "SchmeNm": {
                                                        "Cd": {
                                                            "const": "CUST"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "Id": {
                                                        "minLength": 6,
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "SchmeNm": {
                                                        "Cd": {
                                                            "const": "TXID"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "Id": {
                                                        "oneOf": [
                                                            {
                                                                "maxLength": 8,
                                                                "minLength": 8
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "maxLength": 11,
                                                                "minLength": 11
                                                            }
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "description": "PERU C2C BANK",
    "properties": {
        "Cdtr": {
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "properties": {
                        "PrvtId": {
                            "properties": {
                                "Othr": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Id": {
                                            "pattern": "^[0-9]+$",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "SchmeNm": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "Cd": {
                                                    "enum": [
                                                        "NIDN",
                                                        "CCPT",
                                                        "TXID",
                                                        "ANRU",
                                                        "CUST"
                                                    ],
                                                    "maxLength": 4,
                                                    "minLength": 4,
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "Cd"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "Id",
                                        "SchmeNm"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "Othr"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "PrvtId"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "Id"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Cdtr"
    ]
}
```

This case should be "valid" in case of the first `if` schema but I get an error for the last validation
[image: Error example]

Comment: Which draft version of JSON Schema are you using? You didn't include that information.

Comment: Hi @JeremyFiel thanks for appoint that missing information.

"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in cleaning up the readability a bit, you can use `definitions` to define your complex schemas and then use a `oneOf` to reference each of them.

You can read more about different patterns used in JSON Schema authoring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required/38781027#38781027)

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "https://www.stackoverflow.com/schema/cdtr",
    "description": "PERU C2C BANK",
    "required": [
        "Cdtr"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "Cdtr": {
            "required": [
                "Id"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "required": [
                        "PrvtId"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "PrvtId": {
                            "required": [
                                "Othr"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Othr": {
                                    "required": [
                                        "Id",
                                        "SchmeNm"
                                    ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Id": {
                                            "pattern": "^[0-9]+$",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "SchmeNm": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "required": ["Cd"],
                                            "properties": {
                                                "Cd": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "oneOf": [
                                        {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/SchmeNm_TXID"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/SchmeNm_CUST"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/SchmeNm_OTHER"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "SchmeNm_TXID": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "minLength": 8,
                            "maxLength": 8
                        },
                        {
                            "minLength": 11,
                            "maxLength": 11
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "SchmeNm": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Cd": {
                            "enum": [
                                "TXID"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "SchmeNm_CUST": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "minLength": 6
                },
                "SchmeNm": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Cd": {
                            "enum": [
                                "CUST"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "SchmeNm_OTHER": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "minLength": 6,
                    "maxLength": 8
                },
                "SchmeNm": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Cd": {
                            "enum": [
                                "NIDN",
                                "CCPT",
                                "ANRU"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Jeremy, this work fine, in the page of https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and in your system the validations are working

Answer (score 0):

You missed a few `properties` definitions in your `if` statements where you defined `SchmeNm` and `Cd`

```json
{
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cdtr": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "PrvtId": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Othr": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "SchmeNm": {
                                                        "properties": {  <<--- this was missing on all of your conditional statements. 
                                                            "Cd": {
                                                                "const": "TXID"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

After fixing that, your instance passes

```bash
{
  keyword: 'https://json-schema.org/evaluation/validate',
  absoluteKeywordLocation: 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/schema/cdtr#',
  instanceLocation: '#',
  valid: true,
  errors: []
}
```

Comment: btw, with the original schema you posted, your `required` keywords are defined at the wrong level, they should be up one level as a sibling to `properties`.  You currently have them defined as a sibling to the actual property name and they are ignored